# Multivariate Probability Distribution Expected Value and MGF

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus

Let $X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$ be random variables - continuous or discrete. The joint moment generating function of the random variables is given by
\begin{align*}
  m(t_1,t_2,t_3) = E(e^{(t_1X_1 + t_2X_2 + t_3X_3)}).
\end{align*}

a. Show that $m(t,t,t)$ gives the moment generating function of $X_1+X_2+X_3$.

b. Show that $m(t,t,0)$ gives the moment generating function of $X_1+X_2$.

c. Show that $\frac{d^{(k_1+k_2+k_3)}}{ dt_1^{k_1} dt_2^{k_2} dt_3^{k_3}}m(t_1,t_2,t_3)$  at $t_1=t_2=t_3=0$  is $E( X_1^{k_1} X_2^{k_2} X_3^{k_3})$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the definition of moment generating function you have written.